# Javascript string manipulation url

Tags: javascript

My problem is I am trying to extract certain things from the url. I am currently using

```
window.location.href.substr()
```

to grab something like "/localhost:123/list/chart=2/view=1"

What i have now, is using the index positioning to grab the chart and view value.

```
var chart = window.location.href.substr(-8);
var view = window.location.href.substr(-1);
```

But the problem comes in with I have 10 or more charts. The positioning is messed up. Is there a way where you can ask the code to get the string between "chart=" and the closest "/"?

Comment: You should use a regex.

Comment: Another option is to use a library like [sammy](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy) which makes this template-able and event driven. Also, may want to use `location.pathname` instead of `href`

Comment: window.location.pathname only return a '/' ?

Comment: is regex the same as RegExp?

Comment: @user2539797 yes, RegEx is the common abbreviation, but in _JavaScript_ and some other languages it is called _RegExp_. Both mean "regular expression/s".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "/localhost:123/list/chart=2/view=1";
var data = str.match(/\/chart=([0-9]+)\/view=([0-9]+)/);
var chart = data[1];
var view = data[2];
```

Of course you may want to add in some validation checks before using the outcome of the match.

Inspired by Paul S. I have written a function version of my answer:

```
function getPathVal(name)
{
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var regx = new RegExp('(?:/|&|\\?)'+name+'='+'([^/&,]+)');
    var data = path.match(regx);
    return data[1] || null;
}
getPathVal('chart');//2
```

Function should work for fetching params from standard get parameter syntax in a URI, or the syntax in your example URI

Comment: If its possible, can you explain how the str.match(/\/chart=([0-9]+)\/view=([0-9]+)/) works?

Comment: @user2539797 Sure, the `/` at either end is the delimeter (contains the expression). `\/` matches a forward slash, it then looks for the word chart and an `=` followed by 1 or more numbers (0-9) - then another forward slash (`\/`) the word view followed by a `=` and 1 or more numbers again (`[0-9]+`). The segments surround by parenthesis `()` are stored for retrieval in order (first set of brackets is `data[1]`, second is `data[2]` etc... FYI the reason `/` has to be `\/` is because the parser stops at the second `/` thinking that it's the end of the expression, hence the escaping (backslash)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
function getPathVar(key) {
    var str = window.location.pathname,
        i = str.indexOf('/' + key + '=') + key.length + 2,
        j = str.indexOf('/', i);
    if (i === key.length + 1) return '';
    return str.slice(i, j);
}
// assuming current path as described in question
getPathVar('chart');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split your string up, with "/" as delimiter and then loop through the resulting array to find the desired parameters. That way you can easily extract all parameters automatically:

```
var x =  "/localhost:123/list/chart=2/view=1";

var res = {};
var spl = x.split("/");
for (var i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    var part = spl[i];
    var index = part.indexOf("=");
    if (index > 0) {
        res[part.substring(0, index)] = part.substring(index + 1);
    }
}

console.log(res);
// res = { chart: 2, view: 1}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xmtsu/)**